# using yq to Increment value if field exists

Tags: yaml, yq

I have the following yaml file:

```
name: myapp
app1:
  version: 1.2
  replicas: 1
app2:
  version: 2.3
  replicas: 1
app3:
  version: 4.0
app4:
  version: 2.4
```

I'd like to use yq to increment the values of each replicas field so it results in:

```
name: myapp
app1:
  version: 1.2
  replicas: 2
app2:
  version: 2.3
  replicas: 2
app3:
  version: 4.0
app4:
  version: 2.4
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `select` with `has` to check if the field exists, and `+=` to update it:

Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```sh
yq '(.[] | select(has("replicas")).replicas) += 1'
```

Using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```sh
yq -y '(.[] | select(has("replicas")?).replicas) += 1'
```

Comment: Thanks, really what I needed. Out of curiosity, I did not get the .[] as I though it kind of flattens all the fields. Does it create a list of each object instead ?

Comment: @Luc `.[]` accesses all fields "at once". It's like writing `.app2`, which actually stands for `.["app2"]`, but with an undefined field name, i.e. of any name.